# How to write test cases for Project,Library project in Android studio

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, android-testing

Currently I am working on creating test cases for my Android project which used Another Android project as `Android Library` project. In my Android project I didn't do any business logic I have done all logics in my Android Library project,So I just `extends` my activity into Android library Project Activity. I have written separate Test classes for each Activity in Android Library.If I run each test class It will pass in test.How can I test the whole Android Library Project? and also Android application project?. If I accessed any Android Library project's test class`(AndroidLibraryProject/src/androidTest/java/packageName/testCase.java)` in my Android Application Project it showed `does not exist` error message while run the class.How can I test whole project both `Android application project` and `Library project`

Answer (score 0):

When you run unit-test on project (module ":app") which use another projects as library, it automatically run test on module project/library project.

So write tests for both, try letting tests for library projects at

```
AndroidApplicationProject/src/androidTest/java/packageName/
(not AndroidLibraryProject/src/androidTest/java/packageName/)
```